# Sound Relationships

Tags: waves, acoustics, intensity

Whats the relationship between amplitude, volume, and wave energy. I have tried many websites but none have helped me yet and I believe maybe someone on here can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The Intensity is the power delivered by a wave per unit area.
It is proportional to the square of the amplitude of the wave.

The Loudness, is measured in decibels as a relative intensity, L = 23.03 ln(I/Io)

The energy in terms of the intensity is,
E = IAt

(by the definition of intensity.)

If you were looking for equations relating them, then it depends on the type of wave, whether its mechanical or electromagnetic.